# Footer position at bottom of page(CSS and HTML problems

Tags: html, css, header, footer, fixed

[Stacked Footer and Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1G4B.jpg)

As the picture show the footer and the header are mixed together. I've tried to use 
     
and just 
    
But appears the exact same.
There're a few questions about positioning footer but their versions of CSS are really old so I couldn't fine the place to edit my Footer CSS.
It works if the body under header fill up almost whole page and let footer go after it, but if there's no contents at all, how do I fixed the footer to bottom of the page?
Thank you.

Comment: an answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page

Comment: I've tried all of the methods in there and doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Use css to fix it to the bottom of a screen.

```
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
}
<div id="footer"></div>
```

No need to change your footer. This is just an example as I don't know your actual code.

Some more examples:

```
<div style="position:fixed;bottom:0px;"></div>
<footer style="position:fixed;bottom:0px;"></footer>
```